# T-SQL - GROUP BY with LIKE - is this possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to include a LIKE expression in a GROUP BY query?  For example:

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM tblWhatever
GROUP BY column_x [LIKE %Fall-2009%]
```

column_x:

```
--------
BIOL-Fall_2009
HIST Fall_2009
BIOL Spring_2009
```

Result:

```
------
Fall_2009   2
Spring_2009 1
```

Comment: I don'tquite understand what you want to do.If there was also a row with "HIST Spring_2009", what is the expected result?

Comment: @Cellfish: I believe what the poster wants is to extract the school term out of the denormalized column and group on the school term, throwing out the course name part of the text.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need an expression that returns "Fall_2009" or "Spring_2009", and then group on that expression. eg:

```
-- identify each pattern individually w/ a case statement
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN column_x LIKE '%Fall[_]2009'   THEN 'Fall 2009'
    WHEN column_x LIKE '%Spring[_]2009' THEN 'Spring 2009'
  END AS group_by_value
, COUNT(*) AS group_by_count
FROM Table1 a
GROUP BY 
  CASE
    WHEN column_x LIKE '%Fall[_]2009'   THEN 'Fall 2009'
    WHEN column_x LIKE '%Spring[_]2009' THEN 'Spring 2009'
  END
```

or

```
-- strip all characters up to the first space or dash
SELECT 
  STUFF(column_x,1,PATINDEX('%[- ]%',column_x),'') AS group_by_value
, COUNT(*) as group_by_count
FROM Table1 a
GROUP BY 
  STUFF(column_x,1,PATINDEX('%[- ]%',column_x),'')
```

or

```
-- join to a (pseudo) table of pattern masks
SELECT b.Label, COUNT(*)
FROM Table1 a
JOIN (
  SELECT '%Fall[_]2009'  , 'Fall, 2009' UNION ALL
  SELECT '%Spring[_]2009', 'Spring, 2009'
  ) b (Mask, Label) ON a.column_x LIKE b.Mask
GROUP BY b.Label
```

Comment: I'd like to try out your 1st suggestion but am not sure I know how to structure the statement.. Do you mind posting an example of how/where it fits?

Comment: I've put the first example in context. You could move the group_by_column to a subquery like rexem's solution to avoid the repetition. I think example 3 is the best, though.

Comment: Where is rexem's solution? everybody is referring to his solution but there's no answer by him. Also it turns out for the 1st suggestion if you have more CASES then you need to have specific arrangement otherwise some will be ignored. i haven't figured it out yet, i just see the output and re-arrange the cases if i don't see the output for any case. +1 for saving me time looking for how to use Group By + Like together.

Comment: I think rexem may have changed their username to OMG Ponies. In any case, the rexem solution I mentioned was the same idea as solution 1, but with less repetition by using a subquery. These days you can also use `CROSS APPLY`  to define the define the expression once and then reference it in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses.

Answer (score 3):

No, the LIKE function is not supported in the `GROUP BY` clause.  You'd need to use:

```
  SELECT x.term,
         COUNT(*)
    FROM (SELECT CASE
                   WHEN CHARINDEX('Fall_2009', t.column) > 0 THEN
                     SUBSTRING(t.column, CHARINDEX('Fall_2009', t.column), LEN(t.column))
                   WHEN CHARINDEX('Spring_2009', t.column) > 0 THEN
                     SUBSTRING(t.column, CHARINDEX('Spring_2009', t.column), LEN(t.column))
                   ELSE
                     NULL
                 END as TERM
            FROM TABLE t) x
GROUP BY x.term
```

Comment: Does that work? I would have thought CHARINDEX('Fall_2009', t.column) > 0

Answer (score 2):

LIKE does not make sense in your context, as it either matches or it does not, but it does not establish groups.
You will have to use string functions that parse the column values into what makes sense for your data.

Answer (score 1):

I dont believe so, LIKE is effectively a binary state - something is LIKE or NOT LIKE, there are not logical degrees of 'likeness' that could be grouped together. Then again, I could be off my rocker.

If what you really want is to express filtering over your grouped data take a look at the HAVING clause.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your courses always take five letters, you can keep it really simple:

```
SELECT substring(column_x,5,100), count(*)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY substring(column_x,5,100)
```

Otherwise, check Peters or Rexem's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it this way, but like the others said, doesn't really make sense:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM tblWhatever
GROUP BY column_x 
HAVING column_x LIKE '%Fall-2009%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have a badly structured database, having combined SUBJECT and TERM into the same column.  When you use GROUP BY it treats each unique value in the column as a group in the result set.  You'd be best advised to restructure the database if at all possible — you probably want three columns here (SUBJECT, TERM, SCHOOL_YEAR) but two might possibly be appropriate.

If you can't restructure the database you'll need to parse the column to extract the term.  Rexem showed you one way to do this, you could also use a stored procedure.

Comment: yeah, I knew that going into it - it's not my db to change/redesign or otherwise I would've designed it as you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT MAX(column_x) AS column_x 
FROM (
    SELECT column_x 
    FROM tblWhatever 
    WHERE (UPPER(column_x) LIKE  '%Fall-2009%')
) AS derivedtbl_1 GROUP BY column_x
```

Comment: The OP is looking for group by like, not filter by. This won't work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me

```sql
-- identify each pattern individually w/ a case statement
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN column_x LIKE '%Fall[_]2009'   THEN 'Fall 2009'
    WHEN column_x LIKE '%Spring[_]2009' THEN 'Spring 2009'
  END AS group_by_value
, COUNT(*) AS group_by_count
FROM Table1 a
GROUP BY 
  CASE
    WHEN column_x LIKE '%Fall[_]2009'   THEN 'Fall 2009'
    WHEN column_x LIKE '%Spring[_]2009' THEN 'Spring 2009'
  END
```