# Prevention of mutiple sql sum queries possible?

Tags: mysql

I would like to prevent this:

```
  $florissql = "SELECT SUM(hours) FROM logs WHERE executors LIKE '%floris%'";
  $rosasql = "SELECT SUM(hours) FROM logs WHERE executors LIKE '%rosa%'";
  $lottesql = "SELECT SUM(hours) FROM logs WHERE executors LIKE '%lotte%'";
```

Is it possible to do this in just one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this maybe?

```
 SELECT SUM(hours) AS Hours, 'floris' AS Executor FROM logs WHERE executors LIKE '%floris%'
 UNION ALL
 SELECT SUM(hours) AS Hours, 'rosa' AS Executor FROM logs WHERE executors LIKE '%rosa%'
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT SUM(hours) AS Hours, 'lotte' AS Executor FROM logs WHERE executors LIKE '%lotte%'
```

That'll result in:

```
  Hours | Executor
  ----------------
  123   | floris
  456   | rosa
  789   | lotte
```

Comment: Actually you run three SQL queries instead of one.

Comment: @vag My answer included one statement, which I'd assumed the question was actually looking for. Note the 3 PHP sting variables for 3 separate statements.

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647736/t-sql-group-by-with-like-is-this-possible) shows you how to use `GROUP BY` with `LIKE`... then you can do something like this :

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN executors LIKE '%floris%'   THEN 'floris'
    WHEN executors LIKE '%rosa%' THEN 'rosa'
    WHEN executors LIKE '%lotte%' THEN 'lotte'
  END AS exec
, SUM(hours) AS hrs
FROM logs
GROUP BY 
  CASE
    WHEN executors LIKE '%floris%'   THEN 'floris'
    WHEN executors LIKE '%rosa%' THEN 'rosa'
    WHEN executors LIKE '%lotte%' THEN 'lotte'
  END
```

Then you can match the sum of hours with exec on the different rows.

That question I linked to shows you more advanced methods to in case you need to do more of those...

Answer (score 0):

If results *per executor* are required, the following should suffice:

```
SELECT executors, SUM(hours)
FROM logs
WHERE executors LIKE '%floris%'
OR executors LIKE '%rosa%'
OR executors LIKE '%lotte%'
GROUP BY executors
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    sum(IF(executors LIKE '%floris%',hours,0)) as 'floris',
    sum(IF(executors LIKE '%rosa%',hours,0)) as 'rosa',
    sum(IF(executors LIKE '%lotte%',hours,0)) as 'lotte'
FROM logs;
```

But, you know, usage `%` at first position could kill you DB performance. Because in that case indexes will not using. Try to avoid that kind of requests.