# MYSQL like + group

Tags: php, mysql

Well I'm having a problem mainly caused by bad structure in database. I'm coding this for a company whose code is quite messy and the table is very large so I don't think it's an option to fix the structure.

Anyway, my issue is that I'm trying to somehow group a value that won't be alone in the string...
They are storing values separated with commas... So it would be like

```
field: "category" value: 'var1, var2, var3'
```

And I will search using this query:

```
SELECT name, category 
FROM companies 
WHERE (MATCH(name, category) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
       OR category LIKE '$search%')
```

It would match with for example var2 (it's not limited to 3 variables though, can be solo or many more) and I'd split it manually in PHP, no problem. Although I will not get enough matches, I want e.g. 10 matches by different searches. To be more specific I'm making an autosuggest feature, which means I will for example want to match "moto%" with motorbike, motor alone or whatever but I keep getting the same values, like there'd be a couple of 100 of results that contains "motorbike" and I don't know how to filter them, as I'm not able to use GROUP BY due to bad db structure...

I found this: [T-SQL - GROUP BY with LIKE - is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647736/t-sql-group-by-with-like-is-this-possible)
It SEEMED as something that would be a solution, but as far as I've tried I could not get it work with what I wanted.

So I'm wondering which solutions there are... If there are ABSOLUTELY no way of working this around I might probably have to fix the db structure (but this really has to be the last option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start taking steps to make database structure proper. Make an extra table and fill it with split values.

Then you can use proper queries to select the data you need. Both you and next developer will have less troubles with this project in the future, not mentioning queries speed gain.

Comment: Alright, I'll just do it instead of looking for other options. Do you have any suggestion though, how to split the values into a new DB? Using pure MYSQL or PHP

Comment: Into a new table i meant... I'll just search for it or create a new question if I don't find anything.

Comment: I'd create the new table, run a query like `SELECT name,` (or whatever you choose to use for a unique identifier) `category FROM companies`, then use php to explode() the contents of category.  Use a foreach loop for each category thus generated, insert into the new table the id and the category.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, just wanted to make sure there were no better options before I did so! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why i cannot write a comment, but maybe you can try this:

```
SELECT name, category FROM companies WHERE category LIKE '$search%' or LOCATE('search', category)>0;
```

That would look if in category appears any of your 'search' value.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to agree that you should make the database right.  It'll save you much trouble and time later.  However, using `SELECT DISTINCT` may fix your immediate issue.

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Makes none at all difference, as I said I need to group them by most likely an ungroupable field... The values will never be the same there.