# find the count using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a students table as below

```
Rajesh Kumar
Nagendra Prasad
Bharath kumar
Raghav Kumar
Abhnav Bindhra
```

I need to write a query which will the count of students with names having "kumar" and "Prasad".

```
Kumar   3
Prasad  1
```

How do i do that? I tried with the following query, but i am doubtful on what to place for groupby clause?

```
 Select Name,count(Name) from Student where 
    Name LIKE  ('%Kumar%')
    or Name LIKE  ('%Prasad%')
    group by ???
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [T-SQL - GROUP BY with LIKE - is this possible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647736/t-sql-group-by-with-like-is-this-possible)

Answer (score 6):

```
select  FindName 
,       count(*)
from    (
        select  case
                when Name like '%Kumar%' then 'Kumar'
                when Name like '%Prasad%' then 'Prasad'
                end as FindName
        from    Student
        ) as SubQueryAlias
where   FindName is not null
group by
        FindName
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try the following SQL query:

```
select SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name) + 1, LEN(name)) as lname, count(name)
from Student
where name like '%kumar%' or name like '%Prasad%'
group by SUBSTRING(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name) + 1, LEN(name));
```

If `CHARINDEX` does not work, you may try to use any SQL function to return the index of `<space>`.

> Please consider this as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution.

Comment: It was act of kindness, @theghostofc. thx and +1 for your answer;)

Answer (score 1):

Another option with CASE expression

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Name LIKE ('%Kumar%') THEN 'Kumar' ELSE 'Prasad' END AS Name, 
       COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM Student
WHERE Name LIKE  ('%Kumar%')  OR Name LIKE ('%Prasad%')
GROUP BY CASE WHEN Name LIKE ('%Kumar%') THEN 'Kumar' ELSE 'Prasad' END
```

See example on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/93638/2)

Answer (score 0):

Mysql support regexp.

```
Select Name,count(Name) from Student where Name  REGEXP ('Kumar|Prasad') group by Name  REGEXP ('Kumar|Prasad');
```