# PHP SQL SELECT sum(value) WHERE x LIKE '%$month%' (foreach)

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, foreach, aggregate-functions

I have a table:

```
user_id |       month       | value
    1   | firstname_1_2017  |   5 
    1   | secondname_1_2017 |   4
    1   | firstname_2_2017  |   7 
    1   | secondname_2_2017 |   8
    1   | firstname_3_2017  |   5 
    1   | secondname_3_2017 |   4
    1   | firstname_4_2017  |   7 
    1   | secondname_4_2017 |   8
```

I need sum "value" for each month with a foreach.

firstname_1_2017 + secondname_1_2017 = 9

firstname_2_2017 + secondname_2_2017 = 15

I have an array for the months:

```
$array_months = array( '1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12' );
```

So I wrote (in php):

```
SELECT sum(value)
FROM table
WHERE user_id = $user_id
AND month LIKE '%_$array_months_2017%'
```

When I write a foreach, the result is the same sum of all values repeat for each month (Example: Jan 48 points, Feb 48 points, Mar 48 points...).

I'd like this result with a foreach:

You have "9" points in January

You have "15" points in February

etc...

Comment: Think about your db design. It is not good to store more than one Information in one column

Comment: Paste your PHP code, not just SQL query.

Comment: If you wanna do all the thing with mysql, you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1647857/4641073. Otherwise you can select rows in PHP and do the sums in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the numbers from your `month` column values with [the `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) like this, giving `3_2017`.

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX('firstname_3_2017', '_', -2)
```

You can then transform that to a *date-ish* string with `CONCAT()`, yielding `1_3_2017`.

```
CONCAT('1_',SUBSTRING_INDEX('firstname_3_2017', '_', -2))
```

Then you can turn that into an actual `DATE` value with `STR_TO_DATE()`.

```
STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1_',SUBSTRING_INDEX('firstname_3_2017', '_', -2)),'%d_%m_%Y')
```

Cool, now you have a datatype you can actually work with. You can now use an aggregate query to get good stuff. Leveraging Samir's fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8aabd/6/0

```
SELECT 
  SUM(value) value,
  user_id,
  STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1_',SUBSTRING_INDEX(month, '_', -2)),'%d_%m_%Y') month_begin
  FROM table
 GROUP BY user_id, STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('1_',SUBSTRING_INDEX(month, '_', -2)),'%d_%m_%Y')
```

Summary: simple transformations of your `month` column can give you usable information.

**Pro tip:** when designing your tables try not to stuff values with different meanings into single columns. Read about normalization.

**Pro tip 2:** use actual `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP`, or `DATETIME` values for storing time-based information whenever possible. Date arithmetic and date-based indexing are powerful parts of DBMS servers.

Answer (score 1):

You should think about changing your DB design to separate Month and Year from user's name.

Not a good approach, but a solution will be to extract month year from `month` string and group it to calculate sum for each month.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(month, LOCATE('_', month) + 1) AS month_year, SUM(value)
FROM users
WHERE user_id = 1
GROUP BY month_year;
```

*[Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8aabd/1)*